# Undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass for search form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search

I am creating search form, and I have created search controller and other controller named as user.
Here is the code of **search_controller**

```
def search
  if params[:q]
    @users = User.q(params[:q]).order("created_at DESC").paginate(page: params[:page])
  else
    @users = User.all.order('created_at DESC').paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
end
```

Here is the **search form**

```
<%= form_tag search_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :q, params[:q] %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

But when I search I am getting `undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass` error. Here is the code of **users_controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :destroy] 

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @archings = @user.archings.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User deleted"
    redirect_to users_url
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      log_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Arch"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end

   def logged_in_user
      unless logged_in?
    store_location
        flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
        redirect_to login_url
      end

 end
end
```

Can anyone tell me where I am doing mistake?

PS: I am beginner and new to rails and ruby.

Comment: please post the stacktrace in order to find the file and the line of the error

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/vzC4FrO.png

Comment: And why did you cut off all the juicy bits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `@user` on line 1 is empty that is why you are getting the error.
In your `index` action please change the code as follows:

```
def index
  @users = User.all.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

Without the `all` your `@users` is empty

You will also have to iterate through`@users` in the **index.html.erb** file. That can be done like this:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  Your code 
<% end %>
```

Comment: Now I am getting this error `undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: I guess it's fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

The search object you are returning, is a active record object. It is not one object. You will need to loop through your `@users` and access the name of the result. Something like

```
- @users.each do |user|
  =user.name
```

P.S `@user` is not defined in your search controller. So `@user` is nil.

Comment: now I am getting this `error undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: thanks to all for helping me it worked with few more changes. Again thanks to all of you.